# Swift: Avoid imperative For Loop

Tags: swift, ios8, functional-programming

What I'm trying to accomplish in imperative:

```
var mapNames = [String]()
var mapLocation = [String]()

for valueMap in valueMaps {
    if let name = valueMap.name {
         mapNames.append(name)
    }
    if let location = valueMap.location {
        mapLocation.append(location)
    }
}
```

What's the best way using a high order function or perhaps an array method (`array.filter` etc.) to compact the code above and also avoid using the `for` loop

Here is what I have tried, but the compiler gives an error:

```
let getArrayOfNames = valueMaps.filter() {
    if let name = ($0 as valueMaps).name as [String]! {
        return name;
    }
}

let getArrayOfLocations = valueMaps.filter() {
    if let type = ($0 as valueMaps).location as [String]! {
        return type;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the compiler error?

Comment: I would benchmark any func involving map reduce or filter as sometimes these are slower than using loops and letting compiler unroll them. I've found some for loops are faster than map or filter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need both `filter()` and `map()` :

```
let mapNames = valueMaps.filter( {$0.name != nil }).map( { $0.name! })
let mapLocations = valueMaps.filter( {$0.location != nil }).map( { $0.location! })
```

The filter takes a *predicate* as an argument (which specifies which
elements should be included in the result), and the map takes
a *transformation* as an argument. You were trying to merge both
aspects into the filter, which is not possible.

**Update:** As of Swift 2(?) has a `flatMap()` method for sequences, which
can be used to obtain the result in a single step:

```
let mapNames = valueMaps.flatMap { $0.name }
```

The closure is applied to all array elements, and the return value is an
array with all non-nil unwrapped results.

Answer (score 2):

The filter() function needs its closure to return a bool - not the value you want to store in an array. You could chain filter and map together to get what you want, then:

```
let getArrayOfNames = valueMaps
    .filter { $0.name != nil }
    .map{ $0.name! }
```

Or, to do it in one function, with reduce:

```
let getArrayOfNames = valueMaps
    .reduce([String]()) {
        accu, element in
        if let name = element.name {
            return accu + [name]
        } else {
            return accu
        }
}
```

Actually, the reduce can be a little better:

```
let getArrayOfNames = valueMaps.reduce([String]()) {
  (names, value) in names + (value.name.map{[$0]} ?? [])
}

let getArrayOfLocations = valueMaps.reduce([String]()) {
  (locs, value) in locs + (value.location.map{[$0]} ?? [])
}
```